# Pivot rows to columns inside a View using SQL where column is auto growing

Tags: sql

I have a table with below structure, where row is auto growing.

```
ID  Name        ParameterName     ParameterValue
1   Blood Test  RBC               4.2-5.9
1   Blood Test  WBC               4,300 -10,800
```

I want convert rows into columns as below in a View. Please suggest

```
Id  Name         RBC            WBC                ...
1   Blood Test   4.2-5.9        4,300-10,800       ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If by *"row is auto growing"* you mean to say that new `ParameterName` values will be added in the future, the answer for SQL Server is: you cannot do this from a view. You will need to use stored procedures and in it Dynamic SQL to pivot. I doubt that this possible in ANSI-SQL either.

Comment: A view is a single, fixed query. Any particular query in SQL always produces a result set with the same "shape" - the number of columns, their names and types. The only way around this is to write a new query each time, a.k.a. dynamic SQL, and as TT says, this isn't possible in a view.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the response. As pivot in view couldn't be used in SQL, I changed the structure.